# Is there a way to format exports from azure differently in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I just started working with large quantities of data from Azure and other software products that produce CSVs or excel files that produce information formatted as follows:

[image: Before Conversion]

Is there an easy way to format it like:

[image: After Conversion]

So that it can be used effectively as a table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithmic approach that you can implement in VBA

1. Get references to the Sheet and Range containig the data
2. Copy the Data to a Variant Array variable
3. Loop throught the Data Array rows
4. For each row that column A is Not Empty, capture the value
5. For each row where Column B is Empty, clear Column A
6. For each row where Column B is Not Empty, write the captured value to Column A
7. After the loop copy the Data Array back to the sheet

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Sub TryMe()

' fill down from above
Range("A1:A20").Select ' change the range to suit your needs
Range("A20").Activate
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

' copy/paste values; no references to other cells
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select

' use come logic to do cleanup
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("B1:B20") ' change the range to suit your needs
For Each cell In rng

If cell.Value = "" Then
    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]